# get value from a filter result match

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

How do I get the value of a returned `$filter` match?

for example using this code ...

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$project : {
        "Place"    : {$filter: {input: "$fields",as: "field",cond: { $eq: [ "$$field.name", "ABC" ]}}},
    }}
]);
```

I would get

```
[{"name":"ABC" ,"value":"DEF"}]
```

as the value of `Place`.  I am wondering how to get just the value (`DEF`)

Comment: add another project in aggregation like this `{"$project":{"value":"$place.value"}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from Yogesh, figured it out

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$project : {
        "Place"    : {$filter: {input: "$fields",as: "field",cond: { $eq: [ "$$field.name", "Place" ]}}},
    }},
    {$project : {
        "Place"    : {$arrayElemAt : ["$Place.value",0]}
    }}
]);
```

..wondering if there is a way to single-project it.